# Why doesn't this jQuery hover() work for image src attribute?

Tags: jquery, hover

I have been trying to learn jQuery lately and while tring to crate a hover effect I seemes to have hit a bit of a snag. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $('img.close').hover(function(){
                        $(this).attr('src','images/1.png');
                    },function(){
                        $(this).attr('src','images/2.png');
                    });
});
```

EDIT:I was trying to replace an Image with another Image while Hovering on it beasicly creating a rollover efect

I forgot to mention that the image is created and aded to its container with jQuery

EDIT2:I have managed to find the problem the img.class was created using a animate callback function and it seems that I can't do anything to it except in the callback function the code is corect but not placed in the right place

Comment: What is it doing? Absolutely nothing?

Comment: I am trying to replace an image with another image while hovering on it

Comment: One of these: 1. `img.close` selects nothing. 2. jQuery is not loaded. 3. The image paths are incorrect. 4. You didn't hover over the images, so nothing happened.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rje4F/. A JSFiddle to show that the code you've posted works isolated.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the relevant HTML?

Comment: He has already updated the question stating that the problem was that the image didn't exist when that code was being ran.

Answer (score 0):

If your image src will be images/1.png, then the following code will create rollover effect

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $('img.close').mouseover(function(){
                    $(this).attr('src','images/2.png');
                });
$('img.close').mouseleave(function(){
                    $(this).attr('src','images/1.png');
                });
});
```

EDIT:

This is the hover

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img.test').hover(function(e){
    $(this).attr('src','Img2.jpg'); //event In handler
    alert($(this).attr('src'))
},function(e){
    $(this).attr('src','Img.jpg'); //event Out handler
})
});
```

Hope it may help

Comment: I see this is the accepted as the answer. Could you please explain why your solution works and the original code in the question does not? Thanks!

Comment: @alpacalipsnao This answer doesn't answer the question. The code in question is trying to act on an element that doesn't exist at the time (it is added dynamically). He solved it by using the callback of the code that adds the elements.

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all.  [jQuery `.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) already has `mouseleave()` built right into it.  It's total nonsense to use first half of `hover` along with another `mouseleave`.  Just use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` or simply use `hover` by itself [which combines the two](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: it works because when you hover on the image, its src is changed with HOVER funtion
and for mouseleave, is a saparate funtion which will work when you will leave your mouse from the image... you was creating second funtion which doesnt mean anything.. tho a syntax error

Comment: Then use `mouseenter` instead of `hover`.

Comment: @palsingh: What are you talking about? [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) accepts two parameters.  The first is `mouseenter`, and the second is `mouseleave`.  You are only passing one function to `hover`, that function will be called on **both** `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (on `mouseleave` your other function will be called, but why call 2 function for that event?).

Comment: Using hover as intended would be best.     But instead of replacing hover with mouseenter/mouseleave, you use mouseover/mouseleave.  This answer just keeps  on getting worse.

Comment: You're joking if you think this should be marked as the correct answer.  You took the hover code in the original question (which was written correctly) and rewrote it in increasingly poorer ways.  And you're thanking Rocket for saying the exact same thing I've been saying all along...  `.hover()` is shorthand for `mouseENTER` and `mouseleave`.  YET, you're still using **mouseOVER** instead of **mouseENTER**... **are you not understanding that these are two different things?**  (And there is absolutely no reason to be passing `e` into the functions for this case.)

Comment: If you can't comprehend all the comments so far, especially my last one, then I can't help you.    And the question for you is, how does your hover code solve the OP's problem when his hover code was perfectly fine to begin with?